# ES6 JS Class underscore set and get methods return "Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, underscore.js

I am trying to understand JS ES6 classes and my problem is getting "Maximum call stack size exceeded" when I am reffering to "this." variables. Let's look at this example:

```
class Human {
  constructor(age) {
    this.age = age;
    // "this._age = age;" output:
    // Property age of instance without underscore: 34
    // Property age of instance with underscore: 34
  }

  get age() {
    return this._age;
    // Without underscore error: "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"
  }

  set age(age) {
    this._age = age;
    // Without underscore error: "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"
    console.log(`Without underscore: ${this.age}`);
    console.log(`With underscore: ${this._age}`);
  }
}

let john = new Human(34);
console.log(`Property age of instance without underscore: ${john.age}`);
console.log(`Property age of instance with underscore: ${john._age}`);
```

Why I need to use that underscore in get and set methods? Why outputs are changing like that when i use it in constructor? Why there is no metter I use underscore or not when I am reffering to instance properties? In mdn documentation there is even no underscore at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole point of using `set age` is that you're defining a setter called `age`.

If the implementation of your setter just does `this.age = <new value>`, then you're **recursively** calling the setter.

You can't both have a setter called `age` and try to set a member variable called `age`. They must be called different things, such as `age` and `_age`.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment. To add to Meagar's (correct) answer:

```
set foo (val) {
  // empty
}
```

Is sugar over this:

```
instance.foo = val;
```

So every time some other code sets the `foo` property your setter gets called. The reason *setters* exist is in case you want to do something else, like run some verification to see if the value is valid. So when you have the setter and it is invoked when you do

```
instance.foo = val;
```

Then in the setter you have

```
set foo (val) {
  this.foo = val;
}
```

it is actually invoking itself.